# vb.net JQuery Datatable Takes more time to load

Tags: jquery, vb.net, datatables

I'm using Jquery datatable for a grid.
The records are from SQL DB around (30000 records).
Those records are my customers login information in my application that i can edit it in my Admin page.
Its taking so long to load the table and its styles.
Is there any way to speed up the process.
My application is not a API.

Comment: And what does your customer do with a page of 50000 records?

Comment: If you are trying to fetch, and display, and style 50000 rows, that's not typically done unless you are generating some form of dump file.  To speed things up consider refining the search with user supplied search criteria or switching to a paged display that shows about 20 to 30 records at a shot

Comment: is there any way to show loaded records in front and load remaining in background. Jquery loads all the records first after that only it shows in front.

Answer (score 0):

datatables supports server-side processing: https://datatables.net/manual/server-side

The basic gist is that your API returns a JSON object with the following properties:

```typescript
{
  draw: number;
  recordsTotal: number;
  recordsFiltered: number;
  data: any[];
  error?: string;
}
```

So for example, on the front-end you have:

```js
$('#my-table').DataTable( {
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
        url: '/my-endpoint',
        type: 'POST'
    }
} );
```

And on the backend you have:

```vb
return JsonConvert.Serialize(new With {
  .draw = 1,
  .recordsTotal = 100,
  .recordsFiltered = 0,
  .data = [
    new With { .Id = 1, Name = "Record 1" },
    new With { .Id = 2, Name = "Record 2" },
    new With { .Id = 3, Name = "Record 3" },
    ' etc.
  ]
})
```